# Lista de objetos em Java

Tags: java, variáveis, arraylist, estilo-de-codificação

Qual a diferença entre usar:

```java
List<NomeClasse> lista;
```

E usar:

```java
List<NomeClasse> lista = new ArrayList<Classe>();
```

Já vi das duas formas em projetos diferentes e aparentemente as duas trazem o mesmo resultado, por isso fiquei na dúvida se tem algum jeito que é o certo ou que é considerado boa prática ou se tanto faz a forma de listar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As duas não trazem o mesmo resultado nem de perto.

A primeira linha está declarando a variável e mais nada, ou seja, a variável valerá o valor padrão dela que é nulo para este tipo, então quando for acessar dará erro, a não ser que inicialize depois, mas aí teríamos que observar o resto do código, e não o que foi postado.

A segunda linha, além de declarar a variável, está inicializando uma instância da classe `ArrayList` e colocando um valor para ela com a atribuição, e assim quando for usar encontrará um objeto e não dará erro. No primeiro momento, se não tiver outras partes do código, a lista estará vazia se acessar logo em seguida.

Tipos por referência sempre tem como valor padrão o nulo, então se não vai inicializar pouco depois não existe razão para deixar sem inicialização de forma mais adequada.

Por que vai inicializar depois? Se não tiver uma explicação não faça isso, faça tudo o que precisa o mais rápido possível e evitar problemas. Raramente é interessante inicializar depois, e quase sempre que ver isso é estilo ruim. Mas pode ter algum caso útil.

`nomeObjeto` é algo estranhíssimo aí, então se pegou de algum código jogue ele fora porque está te ensinando errado. Aí deveria ter o nome de uma classe (geralmente começando em maiúsculo) e não algo como que soa ser o nome de uma variável.

Boa prática é a muleta de quem não aprendeu como funciona o que está usando. Quando aprende o mecanismo, a motivação, o porquê de fazer cada coisa, no contexto específico, deixa de ser boa prática e passa ser conhecimento. Conhecimento só existe quando há justificativa. Boa prática é a crença em alguém que não conhece seu cenário concreto.

[image: Crença - Verdade justificada -> Conhecimento]

Nada indica isso ter alguma relação com DTO, parece até estranho, mas pode ser só porque está fora de contexto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).